# How can i use signed division

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture, programmers-notepad

---

> **Hello, I would like to know how can i divide signed number (1001/0011) =(-7/3) , without convert to two's complement  thank
>   you.**

---

Comment: `1001` is already the 2's complement representation of `-7`.

Comment: Your question is unclear, but maybe this can help. Use unsigned division with the positive numbers. The sign of the result is the exclusive or of the input signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use the two's complement to represent the negative number